# Use of strings in Field Calculator algorithm (QGIS Graphic Modeler)

Tags: qgis

I would like to take the first four characters of a field and writte them in a new field using the Graphic Modeler. I'm confused because it seemed to me an easy issue, but trying to reach it working with the field calculator algorithm doesn't work due to the variables behavior in the modeler, I supose.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `Value` (`123` icon), not `Pre-calculated Value` (`ɛ` icon) for the expression input (see screenshot below).
2. You must use an expression that tells QGIS what layer you want to use. As for the layer name, use the variable create by QGIS, named after the layer input you defined (in your case, this seems to be `Trajectes`, check it againg and compare with the screenshot):

```
left (
    attribute (
        get_feature_by_id(  
            @input_layer, 
            $id
        ),
        'campidusuari'
    ), 
    4
)
```

[image]